# Self join between subqueries for duplicate detection

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

I am having some trouble with a query that performs a self join on a sub query, it takes more time than I thought it should and I am having some problems understanding why.

The problem is as follows, Owners can have Items but certain Items may appear twice belonging to different Owners, from each Owner we may get slightly different information about the items, or some field may be null.

Here it is a simple version of my database, it does not contain FK and indexes only exist for IdOwner, IdItem and IdCategry when they appear.

Owner:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | 
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
| IdOwner        | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI |
| IdPlace        | int(10)       | NO   |     |
| SomeDate       | datetime      | YES  |     |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
```

Item:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | 
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
| IdItem         | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI |
| IdOwner        | bigint(20)    | NO   | MUL |
| IdCategory     | int(10)       | NO   |     |
| DupValue1      | varchar()     | YES  |     |
      .
      .
      .
| DupValueN      | varchar()     | YES  |     |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
```

Country:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | 
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
| IdOwner        | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI |
| Country        | Varchar()     | NO   | PRI |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+
```

DupValues 1 to N are the columns that I've found have the most probability to be the same when the item is a duplicate.

This is a simplified version of the query I am currently working with:

```
SELECT subquery1.IdItem, subquery2.IdItem FROM 
(SELECT i1.IdCategory, i1.IdOwner, i1.IdItem, i1.DupValue1, o1.IdSite, o1.SomeDate, COUNTRY.country
FROM ITEMS i1 
LEFT JOIN OWNER o1 ON o1.IdOwner=i1.IdOwner 
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY ON i1.IdOwner=COUNTRY.IdOwner
WHERE i1.IdOwner>9000000) 
as subquery1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT i2.IdCategory, i2.IdOwner, i2.IdItem, i2.DupValue1, o2.IdSite, o2.SomeDate, COUNTRY.country
FROM ITEMS i2 
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY COUNTRY ON i2.IdOwner=COUNTRY.IdOwner
LEFT JOIN OWNER o2 ON o2.IdOwner=i2.IdOwner 
WHERE i2.IdOwner>9000000) 
as subquery2
ON subquery1.IdItem<subquery2.IdItem 
AND subquery1.IdCategory=subquery2.IdCategory 
AND subquery1.IdSite!=subquery2.IdSite AND subquery1.country=subquery2.country 
AND DATE(subquery1.SomeDate)=DATE(subquery2.SomeDate) 
AND (subquery1.DupValue1=subquery2.DupValue1 OR subquery1.DupValue1 IS NULL OR subquery2.DupValue1 IS NULL)
```

There are some more SupValue all with the same format.

The WHERE clause is there to limit the amount of owners as I am still testing the query, when the WHERE clause is in place it limits the owners to ~700k rows and with that number of rows the wuery is taking ~30 minutes process.

When I use explain on the query I get this:

```
+------+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys                          | key         | key_len | ref                    | rows  | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | i1      | range  | PRIMARY,UnivocID,dg_owner,dg_category  | UnivocID    | 8       | NULL                   | 19056 | Using index condition              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | o1      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY     | 8       | i1.IdTender            |     1 |                                    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | country | ref    | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY     | 8       | i1.IdTender            |     1 | Using index                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | i2      | ref    | PRIMARY,UnivocID,dg_owner,dg_category  | dg_category | 4       | i1.IdMolecule          |   657 | Using index condition; Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | o2      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY     | 8       | i2.IdTender            |     1 | Using where                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | country | ref    | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY     | 8       | i2.IdTender            |     1 | Using index                        |
+------+-------------+---------+--------+----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

MariaDB version: 10.1

My 2 questions:

¿Is it `subquery2` being executed for every row of `subquery1` and that is what it is causing the execution time to be that long or is it the nature of the `ON` clauses that is at fault?

¿Can the query be improve, maybe ditching the `JOIN` in favor or another operator?

Comment: Do you need the sub queries, or can this be done directly without sub queries (sub queries might be necessary if you have aggregate functions in them in the full query).

Comment: @Kickstart I need the subquery because I need the data from the 3 tables into 1 and then I need to operate over the result table to detect the duplicates, doing inner join is the only way I know to do that.

Comment: Possible issue is that you are using LEFT OUTER JOINs, hence some of the returned fields will probably be NULLs. And a NULL does not equal a NULL (yet you join based on the country fields being equal). If effect your sub queries have the over heads of LEFT OUTER JOINs but the results are then treated in a way that would means the results could have been from INNER JOINs

Comment: @Kickstart An Item "always" has an Owner and an Owner always has a country so there should never be a NULL country, for the fields that I know can be null I use the last line of the query.

Comment: In which case switch to using INNER JOINs within the sub queries. But that should also mean you do not need to use sub queries.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Do you really need `LEFT`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this as no table layouts or test data (and you also refer to the column called SubmissionDate in the join clause, but that field is not brought back from the sub queries), but the following should avoid using sub queries. Hopefully it will be better able to use indexes:-

```
SELECT subquery1.IdItem, subquery2.IdItem 
FROM ITEMS i1 
INNER JOIN ITEMS i2 
ON i1.IdItem < i1.IdItem AND i1.IdCategory = i1.IdCategory AND (i1.DupValue1 = i2.DupValue1 OR i1.DupValue1 IS NULL OR i2.DupValue1 IS NULL)
INNER JOIN OWNER o1 ON o1.IdOwner = i1.IdOwner 
INNER JOIN COUNTRY c1 ON i1.IdOwner = c1.IdOwner
INNER JOIN OWNER o2 ON o2.IdOwner = i2.IdOwner AND o1.IdSite != o2.IdSite
INNER JOIN COUNTRY c2 ON i2.IdOwner = c2.IdOwner AND c1.country = c2.country 
WHERE i1.IdOwner > 9000000
AND i2.IdOwner > 9000000
```

Comment: This does not work, it is taking even more time, I am thinking it is because the WHERE clause is being applied at the end of the joins, so it is pruning the output only.

"and you also refer to the column called SubmissionDate in the join clause".

My bad, it has been fixed already.

Comment: If you can post the table layouts and some sample data I can try it. But your current query will suffer as MySQL is likely to struggle to pull any indexes through from the sub queries to do the joins on. It can be quicker if you are only returning a tiny bit of data from each sub query, but probably not with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique for investigating or handling dups is to gather the rows together from each table into a single table, then do `GROUP BY` on that table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t
    ( SELECT stuff from one table or set of tables )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT stuff from the other table or tables )
;
SELECT * FROM t
    GROUP BY IdOwner, IdSite, country
;
```

If needed, add an extra column to "stuff" to distinguish the source:

```
SELECT 1 AS source, ...
```

A cause for the poor performance:

```
FROM ( subquery1 )
JOIN ( subquery2 ) ON ...
```

has no indexes (until at least 5.6) on which to perform the `ON`.  So the subquery results are fully scanned.  Even with 5.6, the creation of the index has some overhead.

Another tip, re: `AND DATE(subquery1.SomeDate)=DATE(subquery2.SomeDate)`:  Compute `DATE(SomeDate)` when building the subquery -- this makes it a 1-time process, not a repeated process as the subtable scan is being performed.